# An invalid character was found in text content. Error processing resource

Tags: php, xml

I got the following error,

An invalid character was found in text content. Error processing resource

when I dynamically created xml file using php.The encoding I used was utf-8.I changed it to ISO-8859-1.The error resolved.But the issue is I am having tamil,hindi content So it is displayed as

à®à®à¯à®°à®¾-à®à¯à®à¯à®à¯-

```
header('Content-Type: application/xml'); echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'."\n"; ?> <urlset xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84"> <?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM table "; $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>  <url>  <loc>http://example.com/<?php echo $row[2]; ?></loc>  <lastmod><?php echo str_replace(' ', 'T', $row['dat']).substr(date("O"), 0, -2).':00'; ?></lastmod>  </url> <?php } ?></urlset>
```

How to solve this?

Regards
Rekha
http://hiox.org

---

adding code from comment below:

```
<?
    header('Content-Type: application/xml');
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'."\n";
?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84">
<?php
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM table ";
     $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
    <url>
        <loc>http://example.com/<?php echo $row[2]; ?></loc>
        <lastmod><?php echo str_replace(' ', 'T', $row['dat']).substr(date("O"), 0, -2).':00'; ?></lastmod>
    </url>
<?php } ?>
</urlset>
```

Comment: @rekha You have a history of asking unclear questions and not reacting to replies asking for clarification or more info. That is not encouraging people to help you out and come up with ideas. You need to show some actual PHP code here, and it's not the first time.

Comment: Here is my code

header('Content-Type: application/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'."\n";
?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table ";
 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   ?>
 <url>
 <loc>http://example.com/<?php echo $row[2]; ?></loc>
 <lastmod><?php echo str_replace(' ', 'T', $row['dat']).substr(date("O"), 0, -2).':00'; ?></lastmod>
 </url> <?php } ?></urlset>

Comment: @rekha please edit your question to show the code, it's easier to read there.

Comment: And the obligatory reading link: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: As it turns out, coding your whole page on a single line makes for unreadable code... Also, 0%.

Answer (score 1):

ISO-8859-1 does not have the [coverage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) over hindi and tamil alphabets

Comment: Yes.But the error disappears when I used ISO-8859-1 but tamil fonts are not displaying correctly.